Finding Main Effects from Negative Binomial Regression with Interactions
I have used a Negative Binomial Model for count data. I have 2 predictors. Age (2 or 4), Height ( short, medium, tall). In my model I have Age + Height + Age * Height. For theoretical reasons, my reference levels are Age 2 and short for height. Since I have an interaction, the main effect for age can only be interpreted in reference to a short height. How would I understand the overall effect of age? Could I compare estimated marginal means?
